# Black image bug when exporting highcharts in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg, highcharts, jspdf

I am using highcharts to display several graphs on a webpage which display fine.

I have an export function that tries to combine the charts into a pdf. I am getting the svg of the chart and converting it to a jpeg image to be included in a pdf created by jsPDF.

Here is the code I am using to generate the images:

```
if ($('.chart').length > 0) {
    var chartSVG = $('.chart').highcharts().getSVG(),
        chartImg = new Image();

    chartImg.src = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(chartSVG)));

    var chartCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");

    chartCanvas.width = 600;
    chartCanvas.height = 400;
    chartCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(chartImg, 0, 0, 600, 400);

    var chartImgData = chartCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
}
```

This works perfectly in Chrome but in Firefox it just returns a black image.

Does anyone know what might be going wrong or has seen a similar issue?

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE**

I've updated the code but now no image is appended to the pdf document, either in Chrome or Firefox.

```
if ($('.sales').length > 0) {
        var chartSVG = $('.sales').highcharts().getSVG(),
            chartImg = new Image();

        chartImg.onload = function () {
            var chartCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");

            chartCanvas.width = 600;
            chartCanvas.height = 400;
            chartCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(chartImg, 0, 0, 600, 400);

            var chartImgData = chartCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        }

        chartImg.src = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(chartSVG)));
    }
```

Not sure if I have the code in the correct place.

If I log 'chartImgData' to the console, both browsers generate a dataURI, but Firefox's version differs to Chromes.

**UPDATE**

Fixed the issue with black images. Now i'm struggling with how to return multiple images - how to nest multiple callbacks or is there another way?
Example: [jsfiddle.net/wmuk489c/2](http://jsfiddle.net/wmuk489c/2)

**SOLVED**

Thanks for your help @RobertLangson. fiddle updated with final working code should anyone need it: http://jsfiddle.net/wmuk489c/3/

**FURTHER ISSUES:**

My charts are dynamic and so may not always be present. I need to get an image from each graph that exists. If the graph does not exist, the 'getSVG' function fails, see example: http://jsfiddle.net/wmuk489c/4/

How should the img.onload work if the chart doesn't exist? The first chart in the callback may not be present either, so how would this work? Is there a better way to get the images?

Comment: Does the highcharts SVG chart root `<svg>` element have width and height attributes that are not percentages?

Comment: Yes - they contain fixed widths as defined above. Here is the <svg> element: <svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" style="font-family: 'lucida grande', 'lucida sans unicode', arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600" height="400">

Comment: Move the  doc.save('test.pdf'); inside the inner callback.

Comment: Aha! That's the ticket. Thanks for your help @RobertLongson and putting up with my incompetence ! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setting chartImg.src causes an asynchronous load so you then need to do this...

```
chartImg.onload = function() {
    var chartCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");

    chartCanvas.width = 600;
    chartCanvas.height = 400;
    chartCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(chartImg, 0, 0, 600, 400);

    var chartImgData = chartCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

    doc.addImage(chartImgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 200, 100);

    // You can only do this bit after you've added the image so it needs
    // to be in the callback too
    doc.save('test.pdf');

}

chartImg.src = ...
```

You've a race condition otherwise and I imagine you just happen to get away with it with the Chrome browser on your PC.

[Here's your fiddle fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/wmuk489c/1/).